# Function $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^-$ such that $m<n\implies f(m)<f(n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, order-theory

The title says it all; I'm wondering if there is a sequence $\{f(n)\}_{n<\omega}$ of negative integers such that successive terms get strictly larger.

The issue seems to be that as soon as we fix $f(0)=-n$ we can only strictly increase $n$ times due to the discreteness of $\mathbb{Z}^-$, however my intuition is that the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}^-$ being $\omega$ will admit such a sequence non-constructively by choice.

Comment: consider $-f$ is decreasing function in $\mathbb N$, it has a smallest element.

Comment: @zwim If it is true that in ZF without choice any function into $\mathbb{N}$ must have a minimal element I agree that this settles it, and I think that does hold.  (it should hold in any universe where $\mathbb{N}$ is well-founded I believe)

Comment: It is a theorem of ZF (without choice) that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb N$ has a smallest element.  This holds even though ZF has models whose $\mathbb N$ is not well-founded. This doesn't lead to a contradiction because, even though the $\mathbb N$ of such a model has a nonempty subset $X$ with no smallest element, no such $X$ is in the model.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Fascinating -- even when a set lives inside a given model, its subsets can fall outside that model based on what set-theoretical formulas they are defined by?

Comment: Right. If a set $A$ is in the model $M$, then so is every subset of the form $\{x\in A:M\models\psi(x)\}$ where $\psi(x)$ is a first-order formula in the language of set theory. That's the content of the separation axiom scheme. Other subsets might also be in $M$, but there's no guarantee that all subsets of $A$ are in $M$. (I'm writing this under the assumption that the membership relation of $M$ is genuine $\in$; otherwise, some circumlocutions are needed, but the idea remains the same.)

Comment: Since the title says it all, why would anyone bother to read anything but just the title?  So disregarding everything else to only address the title, you ask the impossible.

Comment: @WilliamElliot You tell me -- more importantly, it looks like these functions are not impossibilities outright, but rather that a given model is never 'aware' of the existence of such a function within the model despite its existence in the outer universe. I am not a model theorist however, so I may have missed some nuance here.

Comment: Recall that the title said it all and accordingly all I have to say about the all incusive title is there is not any such function.

Comment: @WilliamElliot But there is; in particular, there has to be such a function if there are models in ZF with an ill-founded $\mathbb{N}$.  We may define a mapping from $\omega$ into $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ where $X$ has no least element, although this function will not live in the model where that $\mathbb{N}$ is ill founded.  I understand that this may be unfamiliar to someone who does not study or think about model theory, but it is true nonetheless -- your insufficiently nuanced answer is unnecessary.

Comment: None of that was included in the all inclusive title and for the last time, as you made the title say it all, I've already said all that the title merits.

Comment: Actually it was, assuming a sufficiently advanced reader; have a good day friend.